# C++ Assigning heap memory to each element(struct) in array of structs

Tags: c++, struct

I am really confused about allocating memory to struct.

Consider this.

```
struct A {
    ....
}

A* array = new A[5];

// here I am trying to assign memory to array[0]

&(array[0]) = new A; << error
```

but this give me an error

> lvalue required as left operand of assignment`

I am not sure on how to assign memory for `struct A` to `array[0]`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: After the "A* array = ..." line, the memory is there, it's been allocated, it awaits your command. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: `new A[5]` will allocate space and initialize all the 5 objects for you, so you are not supposed to `new A` and assign it to each element in the array. This is C++, not Java.

Answer (score 1):

A type `A*` doesn't hold pointers which should be allocated individually with `new`. An `A*` is a contiguous block of memory which holds 1 or more complete instances of A.

This means that

```
A* array = new A[3];
```

will allocate something like

```
|  A  |  A  |  A  |
```

and each "cell" will be large `sizeof(A)` bytes. So in your case you already have 5 `A` instances, which will be already constructed.

If you want to have indipendent A instances which are allocated on heap then you don't need a `A*` but a `A**`.

```
A** array = new A*[3];
```

This creates a contiguous array of 3 `A*` elements, which are pointers to `A` sort of:

```
|  A*  |  A*  |  A*  |
```

ad each cell is large `sizeof(A*)`.

Now you can assign to an element of the array a specific instance of A allocated on heap. Eg:

```
array[0] = new A();
```

which yields something like

```
|  A*  | ...
   |
   |
   --> |  A  |
```

Answer (score 0):

when you define:

```
A* array = new A[5];
```

You have an array of A. So the memory needed for your five A is already allocated.

You can directly access the element with array[0], etc.

If you want to define an array of pointer on A:

```
A **array = new A*[5];
```

Then you have to allocate memory with:

```
array[0] = new A;
```

Answer (score 0):

The other replies are not wrong, but I just want to give some general advice:

Never use new in C++. new is a low-level function needed only in rare instances when writing library code.

Also never use C-style arrays in C++. Today there are much better alternatives in the standard library. My guess is that you should use std::vector (or perhaps std::array). Now you can work fully with values and avoid pointers.

Answer (score 0):

you should make a clear diffrence between pointer and array

```
A* pointer = new A[2];
A* array[2] = { new A,new A };
```

It will look like this.

```
         memory
           ---
pointer =>  A
           ---
            A
           ---

           ---
array[0]=>  A
           ---
           ...
           ---
array[1]=>  A
           ---
```

Array can save several values.
So you should use A**,a*[N].

```
struct A {
    ....
}

A* array = new A[5];

array = new A; << this will work ,but new A[5] will lost
```